# CKEDITOR :: Get selected text's parent node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am working in CKEditor right now.And I have a Question for You guys.

I am Selecting particular text in CKEditor's Text area and getting the selected

nodes HTML content Using the Below code.

```
 var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
 var sel = editor.getSelection();
 sel.selectElement(sel.getStartElement());
 var ranges = sel.getRanges();
 var el = new CKEDITOR.dom.element("div");

   for (var i = 0, len = ranges.length; i < len; ++i) {
             el.append(ranges[i].cloneContents());
                  }
  alert(el.getHtml());
```

The following returuns the currently selected text HTML content.

```
alert(el.getHtml());
```

My Question is How I get the selected node's parent tag?

**Example**

Example Word is,

```
<p>hi<b>welcome</b>world<p>
```

My Selection is,

```
<b>welcome</b>
```

How do i get the below parent tag.

```
<p></p>
```

Comment: try `var sel = editor.getSelection().getSelectedElement();
alert( element.getName() );`

Comment: sorry,i'm trying this but i does't work.

Comment: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.selection

Comment: I have been view those Docs but it's also should not to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i find the answer.

```
//Get range
range = xhtmlCKEditor.createRange();

range.setStart(anchors[0].tag , 0 );
range.setEnd(anchors[0].tag.getLast(), 1 );

var firstNode = range.startContainer.getParent();
var lastNode = range.endContainer.getParent();
if(lastNode.type === CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT && lastNode.getName() === "span")
{
    range.setEndAfter(lastNode);

}

//Make end Get full if is tcElement
if(firstNode.type === CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT && firstNode.getName() === "p")
{
    range.setStartBefore(firstNode);
}
xhtmlCKEditor.getSelection().selectRanges([range]);
```

Then print the Selection it will get the html With **parent tag**.